# clearRect not clearing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I make a square every second moving it along the page slowly. I then call clearRect to clear the canvas so the old squares are removed and only the new square remains but I'm doing something wrong and the canvas is not cleared.

- How do I get the clearRect to clear the old squares?

The previous questions I've read revolve around using 'draw()' but I'm not using this.

HTML

```
<canvas id="canv1" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
<input id="counter" style="width:40px;"></input>
```

JS

```
i = 1;
c=1;

window.onload=function(){
  hello();
}

function hello(){
  setInterval(function(){func()},1000);
}

function func(){
  var x = document.getElementById("counter");
  x.value = c;
  var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
  var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
  ctx.rect(20+c,20,40,40);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
  ctx.stroke();
  c++
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ys9Yk/1/

Comment: If you're going to use paths (`rect` instead of `strokeRect`) you need to begin and close the path: `ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);ctx.beginPath();ctx.rect(20+c,20,40,40);ctx.closePath();ctx.stroke();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strokeRect`:

```
setInterval(func, 1000);

var x = document.getElementById("counter");
var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
var i = 1;
var c = 1;

function func() {
    x.value = c;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ctx.strokeRect(20 + c, 20, 40, 40);
    c++;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ys9Yk/6/

Comment: Agree. Also note that this declares and initializes the x, d, and ctx variables only once, instead of every time your function calls.